# When installing MailChimp pop-up js I get Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether and Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mailchimp

Using Wordpress and Understrap. When I install the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-
forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false">
</script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-
forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us1.list-
manage.com","uuid":"5792cac24346d164eb0cf6ad2","lid":"c1462a4600"}) })
</script>
```

which works and creates a pop-up for an email subscription I get the error:

```
theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:2 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether 
(http://tether.io/)
    at theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:2
    at theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:3
    at theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:3
(anonymous) @ theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:2
(anonymous) @ theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:3
(anonymous) @ theme.min.js?ver=0.5.7:3
```

and:

```
woocommerce.min.js?ver=3.2.6:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cookies is not 
defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (woocommerce.min.js?ver=3.2.6:1)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

and the js and ajax used in my theme no longer works on the page. If you go to REMOVED you can see that I have ajax and js being used so that when you click on the artists icons it shows series and then products which link to product pages. Once I install the MailChimp pop-up code none of ajax or js works, so if you click on the icons nothing happens.

My theme.js file has always contained Tether 1.4 and is before Bootstrap.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install the MailChimp code in your WordPress implementation, be sure it ends up being placed last in the footer by specifying a very large [priority](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/actions/#priority).

Like so:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'so_48236002', PHP_INT_MAX );

function so_48236002() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us1.list-manage.com","uuid":"5792cac24346d164eb0cf6ad2","lid":"c1462a4600"}) })</script>
<?php }
```

Note that the [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) constant is very large. Suggest you set accordingly. ;)